# Render dojo chart with wkhtmltopdf and KnpSnappyBundle in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, dojo

I am trying to render a html page with af dojo spider chart. 
When I am using the html that is rendered from Symfony2.3 and the dojo javascript I have managed to get the page, with the chart showing correctly, using wkhtmltopdf and a php wrapper called WkHtmlToPdf (http://mikehaertl.github.io/phpwkhtmltopdf/).
When I try to render the page with KnpSnappyBundle, I get the page and text but not the chart. The same happens when I use WkHtmlToPdf in a Symfony Controller.
Any ideas to where the problem can be?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would probably be rendering your charts on the server-side using PHP directly instead of using a JavaScript library that renders the chart in a headless browser (memory-issues).

A good PHP graphing library is [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Your are probably right, but I also need the possibility to hide/show different parts of the spider charts when the chart is showed in the web browser. I think it only possible in a javascript solution.

Comment: Could you please phrase **one** clear question then and describe the requirements a bit more in detail? I thought the question was how to render a chart into a pdf (possibly using dojo spider chart).

Comment: What I am saying is that I want to use dojo for both the webpage and the pdf, and I can't get wkhtmltopdf to render the chart when I am using symfony2.3 and KnpSnappyBundle. My problem is that in test outside Symphony2 it works but it doesn't in Symfony2.